# How can I have masm to generate just machine code?

Tags: assembly, nasm, masm

nasm can generate only machine code by `-f bin` option. I wanted to do the same thing on masm but I can't find how.

It looks always the object code generated is in COFF format and doesn't seem to be such option to turn it off.

Any advice?

Comment: Wouldn't you use the linker to produce an executable?

Comment: You can pound a nail with a screwdriver if you're determined enough. Easier to use a more appropriate tool for the job at hand! What's the objection to Nasm? Or what's the advantage to Masm? More information about exactly what you need to do may help us help you...

Comment: @BoPersson: Right, I'm not trying to create any executables with asm. What I'm gonna produce is a chunk of native code to embed in other executable.

Comment: @FrankKotler: As written above, I'm trying to generate a chunk of native code to embed into another executable. The build system that includes the executable is based on VC++, that's why I'm gonna assemble my code with masm. I'm sure I can use nasm on win32 if masm has no such option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.  But if you goal is simply to write a block of binary to a file, you can easily abuse an assembler into helping you.

Write your assembler program with two parts

- The part you want to produce as a binary block.  Give it a starting label, BLOCK, and and ending label, BLOCKEND.
- A part which gains control when the executable is loaded, and makes a call on the OS (e.g, Windows) to write the block to a file;  when done, it simply exits.  The actual calls to do this aren't actually very difficult to write; you'll likely have 50-100 lines of code in this section.

Comment: Thanks. Your solution looks fine but I have decided to simply crop out the section from COFF format.

Answer (score 1):

`MASM` must use the linker, but it's still possible by using the `/TINY` option to skip the creation of an executable header. See the MS info on creating a COM executable - which is a flat binary file:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/24954

As others have already said, there are less restricted tools. [FASM](http://flatassembler.net/) is my preference - produces a flat binary by default. :)

Comment: This would be the best solution if that is really available though, the version of masm I'm using(11.00.51106.1) doesn't recognize the option.

Comment: The `.MODEL` directive accomplishes the same thing.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ss9fh0d6(v=vs.80).aspx

It's been a few years since I've used MASM, but that documentation looks current.

Answer (score 0):

You could make your masm code into an exe and the use a hexadecimal editor to view the machine code

Comment: Yeah if I were the assembler I'd write out just what I viewed ;)